What are the design considerations for taper angle for a ball fitting into a cone, designed to serve as a fluid seal?
I'm designing a simple valve.  It uses a spring to push the ball into place, and when fluid pressure is great enough the ball is forced back. (Fluid flows from left to right in the below image.) 
Nothing that doesn't exist a thousand times before, but my housing needs some custom features so here I am making my own.
What are the design considerations for the taper angle? Is there an optimal one?
(The fluid which prompts my question is motor oil at low velocities (i.e. low Reynolds numbers), but I'm also just curious for all fluids, possibly including gases.)

What have you checked in terms of viscosity, flow rate ie orifice size, pressure losses and laminar or turbulent flow?

@SolarMike nothing, and unless it's critically important for the taper angle I feel like it's outside the scope of this question. If it does matter, for instance because the dominant factor is the non-turbulent critical angle for a non-compressible fluid, then that's interesting and useful! But it would also be helpful to establish upper and lower ranges, such as "below x degrees the ball will jam" and "above y degrees the ball won't seal".

First up I wouldn't seal on the point where the taper merges with the main outlet pipe. Secondly you need to specify how much force you can apply to unseal it. Thirdly I suspect the ratio of the Young's modulus of the ball and the socket will matter.

@GregLocock 1) where would you seal? (note that I updated the description to make it clear fluid flows from left to right), 2) would the MoE of the ball not be orders of magnitude stiffer than the effective MoE of a spring pushing the ball into the taper? 3) When I see these kind of bypass systems on oil filters the forces involved seem low, on the order of Newtons or tens of Newtons.

I'd seal on the taper itself... but have never designed a ball valve. Here's what I meant figure 2 in this https://www.mdpi.com/2075-1702/10/10/959 but there are plenty of designs that seal on edge like your drawing.

@GregLocock that's a fantastic paper in the link! ("Analysis of Ball Check Valves with Conical and Spherical Seat Designs from Common-Rail Pumps" in case the link dies in the ensuing years.) Thanks a lot for sending it this way.

Great. As Westheimer said "A month in the laboratory can often save an hour in the library. "

Should check out the use of ball valves in automatic gearboxes...
